# Querying Elasticsearch large index from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I have an Elasticsearch index with near to 320 million documents, whose size is 68 GB and it is divided into 5 shards.

What I want is to read the entire index from Spark to convert it to parquet format. However, the data is too large to fit in memory and thus the following exception appears:

```
ERROR NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Read timed out); no other nodes left - aborting...
ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[127.0.0.1:9200]] 
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:149)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:466)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:450)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:391)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In this way, I tried setting scroll.limit property to 1000 in order to read the data in chunks of 1000 documents but the same exception is thrown. Looking at the official documentation I came across with "sliced scroll" where the scroll_id has to be managed to be able to process the next batch. Correct me if I am wrong but, theoretically, Spark would have to loop the data batch by batch until there is no more data. However, I could not find how to implement this with Spark.

I fixed this by manually filtering (push-down) the data and thus reducing the amount of data requested to Elasticsearch. I used the timestamp to limit the response of the query. I had to query many times Elasticsearch to be able to read the entire index. Basically, I did the sliced scroll manually. As you can see, this is not an optimum way to solve the problem. So, do you have any suggestion on how I could address it to read the entire data in an automatic way?

Note that both Elasticsearch and Spark are running on my local machine (16 GB RAM and 4 Cores). Here are my code and dependencies:

**Code with scroll limit (fails)**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("ElasticSearch to Parquet")
    .set("es.nodes", "localhost")
    .set("es.port", "9200")
    .set("es.index.auto.create", "false")
    .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "false")

val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate()

val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("scroll.limit", 1000)
    .load("my-index/index")

df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("data/data.parquet")
```

**Code with push-down filtering (works by repeating the query as many times as needed and changing the starting and ending timestamp)**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("ElasticSearch to Parquet")
    .set("es.nodes", "localhost")
    .set("es.port", "9200")
    .set("es.index.auto.create", "false")
    .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "false")

val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate()

val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
    .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .load("my-index/index")

val filter = df.filter(df("timestamp").gt("dateStart").and(df("timestamp").lt("dateEnd")))

filter.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("data/data.parquet")
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As far as i can understand the problem is not the size basically , it is something that your spark is not able to connect to ES ! How are you running spark and ES and is ES accessible from all the nodes ?

Comment: Spark successfully connects with ES. In fact, the second example I put works fine. However, when I use scroll limit, at first, it works but then the exception is thrown after a while. I have installed ElasticSearch on my local machine (Windows 10). I run the Spark program from IntelliJ in local mode.

Comment: From the exception, it looks like the problem is that ES becomes non-responsive rather than problems with spark memory. Is scroll.limit the right property, it seems to be called scroll_size in the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html). As a side note the filter push-down solution is naturally better with elastic search as it's designed for index lookups rather than full scans, and it's also easy to scale - you can run multiple queries in parallel provided you have enough capacity for both spark and elastic search.

Comment: You are right. I have run ES and Spark on different machines and now it the scrolling seems to work even though it's very slow, but this is another question. Apparently, my computer is not powerful enough to handle both. I have also replaced scroll. limit by scroll. size and increased its value to 10,000. As an additional detail, I have noticed that spark is not the problem, as it only uses a few KBs of memory, so the slow performance is given by ES.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a network issue `Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Read timed out); no other nodes left - aborting...`

I explain how Spark (I mean Spark + elastic4Hadoop lib) is working with elasticsearch:

- elasticsearch split data into `shards`, available via HTTP on data nodes (if HTTP enabled)
- Spark split data into `partitions of RDD`

Since you set `es.nodes.wan.only` to `false`, Spark will first `GET /_cat/nodes` to get the elasticsearch cluster nodes IPs, then map IPs <-> shard.

So when Spark fetch data, each Spark worker tasks can talk to any elasticsearch node shards, on different elasticsearch node. Thats why collocation is often a very idea (put Spark worker and elasticsearch on same machine, that the idea of `big data`, try to execute computation as closest as possible).

Also, the most important tuning here: "have many shards as Spark workers have CPUs". (but this is no more true since es6 with `sliced scroll` feature).